# NullReferenceException when adding Identity in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 webapp that uses EF Core for its database management and ASP.NET Identity functionality to manage users. This webapp works without issues.

Now, I wanted to develop a standalone console application that is used to perform maintenance tasks on the Database (seeding, cleanup operations, factory reset, etc.)

However I'm running into a problem.
I've added to the maintenance app's initialization steps the same instructions I use on the webapp to configure EF Core and Itentity, which are very simple:

```
private static IHost CreateHost(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    builder.ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
            });

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyUser>(opt => { });
            services.AddScoped<MyDbService>();
        });
    return builder.Build();
}
```

however, while these instructions work correctly in my webapp, in the console app they don't. In particular, I get a `NullReferenceException` when invoking `services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyUser>(opt => { });`

There is no inner exception or other info in the message. The stack trace is like this:

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.GetApplicationAssembly(IdentityBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<AddDefaultUI>b__0(ApplicationPartManager apm)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(IMvcBuilder builder, Action`1 setupAction)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddDefaultUI(IdentityBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.AddDefaultIdentity[TUser](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at MainetnanceApp.Program.<>c.<CreateHost>b__2_0(HostBuilderContext _, IServiceCollection services)
```

Why is this happening? Does it have something to do with the fact that it is a console app rather than a webapp? How can I fix this?

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.cs#L67) for `GetApplicationAssembly` doesn't appear to have many opportunities for an NRE.  Is it possible you were allowed to add a null service reference elsewhere in your code?  (asking based on the implementation in the source code)

Comment: Seems like `AddDefaultIdentity` is meant for a web app and not a console App (it adds UI, token providers, and configures authentication to use identity cookies). Have you tried using `AddIdentityCore` instead?

Comment: @MateusSchneiders: that was it! Using AddIdentityCore works perfectly! Rewrite your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AddDefaultIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionuiextensions.adddefaultidentity?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is meant for a web app and not a console App.
It adds UI, token providers, and configures authentication to use identity cookies.

For console apps, you can use [`AddIdentityCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-6.0) instead.

Comment: Works correctly! Just an additional note: you must add this call to the chain  `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()` to properly use the Identity functionalities (for example to inject a `UserManager`, which is what I was trying to do)